How to fix Google Default App Engine not existing issue?
Getting an issue where google cloud deploy says the default app engine is not existing
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Ok], message=[Default service account '@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist. Please recreate this account or specify a different account. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.]
This error comes from attempting to deploy a new version of a google cloud function that is already up and running. Throughout this entire process, that specific service account is Enabled and existing on the Service Accounts tab. Attempts at other service account creations have been made with many roles like 'Editor' and 'Service Account Admin', however these simply say invalid permissions.

Your question is unclear but the error is clear. The project's App Engine Service Account was deleted and should be recreated. See undelete a service account

The first half of that service account's address is missing. How are you getting that error message - is it from a script you're running? Please edit your question to include some (redacted) code to show us how you got to this error.

I just removed the first part of the service email for posting, it is there in the service accounts list like normal.
So a command like gcloud functions deploy <function_name> --entry-point <function_http> --runtime python310 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --project 
will produce this error message.
